# Running multiple jar files in the background automatically even after reboot

Tags: java, centos

Server is running CentOS

I usually run several commands everytime after reboot and I have to do several reconnects to the host just to get it done. Is there a way to run these commands automatically even if the server has been rebooted?

```
nohup java -jar /Application/App1/App1.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App2/App2.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App3/App3.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App4/App4.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App5/App5.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App6/App6.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App7/App7.jar &
nohup java -jar /Application/App8/App8.jar &
```

I would still like to have the option to use pkill on each one if needed be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about putting a script into the /etc/init.d/ directory, so that it will be run on startup?

Comment: Or better still, create a systemd service script

Comment: You can create cron job for this.